# window navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation

i make use of this script bellow to alert a user on navigating to a new window but once the script is on my page and any link is clicked instead the browser to process the clicked link it will still query the user of navigating to the new window and also opens the navigation will loading the clicked link, but if i use "onunload" instead of "onbeforeunload" it will open a clicked link but also in the process it will still alert for navigation:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
window.open("http://www.google.com");
return "go to google instead?";
}
</script>
```

please how can i be able to navigate the user to a new window on attempt to close the current window without the script disturbing my links

Answer (score 0):

It's the 'onbeforeunload' event. It will fire for all times the page is going to go away.

There's another answer here that's possibly going to halp you : [Internet Explorer calling window.onbeforeunload on window.open and AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658481/internet-explorer-calling-window-onbeforeunload-on-window-open-and-ajax-calls)